# Custom ListView Row template in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, visual-studio, xaml

I'm new to WPF app developing and there is no such thing as RelativeLayout(Where I can arrange views relative to another view...like in Android).
My listview row Template looks like this.

[image: Row Template]

**Can someone help me with the code to design such template in XAML**

EDIT : This is the code I've tried so far(Only for the first row i.e for name, time and date)...It doesn't seem to work.

```
 <ListView x:Name="listView" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="752" Margin="20,282,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="486" >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
                        <!--<ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>-->
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" Text="{Binding Time}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                    <!--<TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Background="Gainsboro" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Text="{Binding Date}" TextDecorations="Underline" Foreground="Blue" Cursor="Hand" />-->
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

The Time and Date appear beside each other. I thought using flow direction should help.

Comment: It would be easier for us to help if you could provide some code of what you have tried so far.

Comment: I'm sorry...now I've added the code snippet of what I was working on. Please check

Comment: You might want to go a bit more into detail which part you need help with. For basic layouting I suggest you take a look at the existing panels beside Grid, especially StackPanels and DockPanels as well as the properties Margin, Padding, HorizontalAlignment and VerticalAlignment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Time}" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="{Binding Header}" FontWeight="Bold" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="{Binding Details}" FontWeight="Bold" />

    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

**NOTE:** Avoid some syntax error because I developed in notepad. It is not having any scrollbar as shown in image in your question. You can comment if any issue. You can apply text formatting and margin as per need.